# Android Placerholder "%d can't format java.util.ArrayList arguments"

Tags: java, c#, android, arraylist

I get this exception

> %d can't format java.util.ArrayList arguments

This is my code

In strings.xml

```
<string name="YOU_HAVE_NEW_FRIEND_REQUESTS">You have %1$d requests.</string>
```

C# (server send this to client)

```
Params = new string[] { client.friendrequests.ToString() }
```

And this to show notification

```
showNotification(String.format(getStringResourceByName(message), jsonArrayToArray(json.getJSONArray("Params"))));

private ArrayList<String> jsonArrayToArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray jArray = jsonArray;
    if (jArray != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                listdata.add(jArray.get(i).toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return listdata;
}
```

Comment: d is for int, try with s

Comment: It's work but the message "You have [3] requests"

Comment: then try leaving the d, and change the types on the server and list to int

Answer (score 0):

Please use : `<string name="YOU_HAVE_NEW_FRIEND_REQUESTS">You have %1$s requests.</string>`

Hope it helps in your requirement.

Comment: the result:
"You have [3] requests"

Comment: You're directly using jsonArray object. Get string from it then use String.format method. By default json array has [ ] braces.

Comment: Do you have a example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566533/android-how-to-parse-jsonarray-from-string

Comment: please follow above link. Hope it answer your requirement.

Comment: can you paste the code that you are using to retrieve values from jsonarray.